# Is it possible to create a multiline cell with pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlite

Some cells of my SQLite table exceed the length of pandas display settings in the terminal. Is there a way to make a long cell of information word-wrap to another line?

Here is my code:

```
def view_work(self, CID):
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
    sq="SELECT * FROM Work_Done WHERE CID=?;"
    df=pd.read_sql_query(sq, self.conn, params=CID)
    df=df.set_index("Date")
    df=df.sort_values(by=['Date'])
    return df
```

Here is the current DataFrame output:

```
Date                                                Work_Done Parts_Installed /                   
2018-12-20  Installed computer and removed all of the pre-...                   
2018-12-22  Worked on getting Antivirus instlaled. Set up ...            None
```

What I want is:

```
Date                                                Work_Done Parts_Installed /                   
2018-12-20  Installed computer and removed all of the pre-
            installed software. Joined computer to domain 
            and setup network applications for user.           
2018-12-22  Worked on getting Antivirus installed. Set up a  
            printer/fax machine. Loaded software for user and
            showed them how to use the computer.                          None
```

Is it possible to word-wrap my 'Work_Done' cells when they exceed the maximum length of display?

Comment: I want this too

Comment: Is there a solution for this? This would be so useful, but everyone is suggesting to use `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)` which simply creates  extremely long lines.

Answer (score -1):

`pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)` should do the work for you. It will set the column width to unlimited with no overflows (which means without "..." but with automatic linebreaks). Check in the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html).

Comment: This does not work. It simply creates an extremely long line with no "automatic" line breaks.